# Como controlar un accordion menu

Tags: menú, accordion

Hola   tengo un menu tipo accordion  que se abre  con un click , pero al abarir  dos  panes se quedan abiertos  los dos , me gustaria  siempre  tener un solo pane abierto 
el codigo que uso es

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
 $(document).ready(function() {
    //Initialising Accordion
    $(".accordion").tabs(".pane", {
        tabs: '> h2',
        effect: 'slide',
        initialIndex: null

    });
    //The click to hide function
    $(".accordion > h2").click(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass("current") && $(this).next().queue().length === 0) {
            $(this).next().slideUp();
            $(this).removeClass("current");
        } else if (!$(this).hasClass("current") && $(this).next().queue().length === 0) {
            $(this).next().slideDown();
            $(this).addClass("current");

        }
    });
});
//></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mira este ejemplo realizado con jQuery. Es bastante sencillo y te puede servir.

**Código:**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Accordion</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
    ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
    amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
    odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet
    purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor
    velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In
    suscipit faucibus urna.
    </p>
  </div> 
</body>
</html>
```